# No tests were found - Empty test suite when running jUnit 5 testcase on bare-bone Spring Boot Maven project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, junit5

so we got the message

```
Process finished with exit code 0
Empty test suite.
```

When trying to run Junit5 testscases on our multi module project, so for testing the sources of the issue, I decided to try a new project from scratch (I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4).

I am getting the same issue with the following simple project POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.org.bu.dep.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I tried with/without the junit-vintage-engine same results.

Follows is the test class:

```
package com.org.bu.dep.app.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        Assertions.assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

On the Run window, it says `No tests were found`.

I tried many variations such as with/without `@SpringBootTest` annotation, I tried `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` as well to no avail.

I already googled and most results/SackOverflow answers seem to be from 2016/2017 focused on older versions of IntelliJ which had issues with Junit 5, which do not seem to be related.

Please, any advice?
If we spend too much time on it will be forced to revert to 4, and I very much do not wish to do that :)

Comment: Where is test file in project structure?

Comment: Under /src/test/java/package.name.long... `java` is what is marked as test sources

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So, what works for Junit 5 with Spring Boot 2 is the following 3 TOGETHER:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Tested and verified with empty project.

Please note that @[Michael Legart's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53208817/373091) answer suggesting to add

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
</plugin>
```

Is needed for maven test (and Jenkins) to detect and execute the tests!

Comment: This worked for me. Though  I have added maven surefire plugin of version 3.0.0.M4

Answer (score 29):

In my case, I had a `private` test method - it should be `public`.

Answer (score 8):

Adding mine to the list of "dumb" mistakes: I imported the wrong `@Test` annotation. Junit5 will only consider methods annotated with `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` and not `org.junit.Test`.

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me.

Don't use the version yourself add `junit-bom`

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Also with `maven-surefire-plugin` don't add the version

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure this is because Spring Boot 2 is not using the required Maven Surefire plugin version for JUnit 5. Try with:

```
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.22.1</version>
   </plugin>
```

JUnit5 support was added in 2.22.0, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1330

Comment: That didnt work either, I just tested. What worked is added `junit-jupiter-api` and `junit-jupiter-params` dependencies

Comment: You were actually close - this plugin is required for maven test to run! Its not required to run via IntelliJ, but is for maven test as well as for Jenkins to work. So thumbs up on a helpful answer!

Answer (score 2):

Go to: File -> Project Settings -> Modules and add the below dependency.

[image: add dependency]

add '**com.github.database-rider:rider-junit5:1.2.5**'

[image]

'**com.github.database-rider:rider-junit5:1.2.5**' will make tests find and run.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Intellij. Did you mark your `java test folder` as `Test Sources Root`?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it was not that... Turns out the missing part was adding `junit-jupiter-api` and `junit-jupiter-params` dependencies to the project! I am not sure why though...lol

Answer (score 0):

Using IntelliJ, I had to delete the target folder and run tests to get rid of this error

Comment: Your solution adds nothing above the existing accepted answer, although I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but maybe it helps someone.
I got the error message because I copy-pasted a method from a scratch file where the method was declared `static`.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your tests in interfaces or abstract classes, *e.g.*

```
public interface FooTests() {

  @Test
  default void fooTest() {
    ...
  }
}
```

which then get implemented by a "real" tester class,

```
public class Tester() implements FooTests, BarTests {
  ...
}
```

then what might be happening is that you ran one of those tests for the first time by itself, causing IntelliJ to remember its run configuration thereafter as `FooTests::fooTest` when really it needs to be `Tester::fooTest`. You can override this by modifying the test's run configuration, *e.g.*

[image]

You want to replace the *Method:* class with your non-interface, non-abstract test runner class.