# No tests were found - when using JUnit5 [in IntelliJ IDEA]

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, java-11

Project, with Java 11 and JUnit 5 stack, keeps outputting *"No tests were found"* in IntelliJ IDEA, if running tests (accordingly, not running any test if tried via maven's surefire plugin `mvn test`).

I've tried many variations, and finally figured out the solution. If the `pom.xml` has

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version> //I suppose this is important entry in this problem
</parent>
```

then tests won't run and instead IntelliJ would always print *"No tests were found"*; however, this is **immediately resolved** if I simply remove `<parent/>` element from the `pom.xml` or change its version to `2.3.0.RELEASE`

OK, the problem is solved like that, and it seems like some plugin or transitive dependency problem; however, any ideas what exactly mismatches with JUnit5 engine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No tests were found - Empty test suite when running jUnit 5 testcase on bare-bone Spring Boot Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53179735/no-tests-were-found-empty-test-suite-when-running-junit-5-testcase-on-bare-bon)

Comment: No, it doesn't. The problem is solved per se, as I have stated in my question. The specifics are interesting in versions, namely - my question is what exactly conflics with JUnit5 engine.

Comment: I think the previous versions of spring didn’t include the junit5 Jupiter runtime dependencies. You will be able to compile your code using the Jupiter API, but there won’t be any impl for that. You can verify this theory by running a Gradle scan against both versions of spring, or by explicitly adding the junit runtime dependencies with older spring.

Comment: Have you tried what I had suggested?

Answer (score 2):

In your JAVA test file, make sure you `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;` and not `import org.junit.Test;`.