# No Tests Were Found - Spring - MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, testing

I'm trying to run tests on my project but I get the error: No Tests Were Found.
I'm using Spring Boot with Java 11
My database is MongoDB
Here is a mongo container class with test annotations:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = MongoContainer.DockerMongoDataSourceInitializer.class)
@Testcontainers
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public abstract class MongoContainer {
    @SpyBean
    protected DeviceDao deviceDao;
    @SpyBean
    protected Datastore datastore;
    @MockBean
    protected Connection connection;
    @MockBean
    protected SentryClient sentryClient;

    public static final MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mongo:4.4.0"));

    static {
        mongoDBContainer.start();
    }
    public static class DockerMongoDataSourceInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {

            TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(
                    applicationContext,
                    String.format("spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://%s:%s", mongoDBContainer.getContainerIpAddress(), mongoDBContainer.getMappedPort(27017)));
        }
    }
}
```

All the test classes extends MongoContainer and end with Test or Tests.

Here is a sample:

```
public class DeviceServiceTests extends MongoContainer {

    @Test
    public void deActivateOldDeviceTest(){
        assertThat(true).isEqualTo(true);
    }
}
```

Any Idea what may be the problem? If any more info is needed please let me know. I'll add to the post.

Extra Info:
I'm new to Spring and the project and just started working on it.

I played with pom.xml a lot. I could not solve the problem.
This topic didn't help: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53179735/no-tests-were-found-empty-test-suite-when-running-junit-5-testcase-on-bare-bon)
Also I searched a lot more but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Check if you are using correct imports for `@Test` annotation depending on Junit version you want to use.

Comment: Check if surefire plugin is using the corrent runner if you're using Maven.

Comment: I checked both. unfortunately, non solved my problem. :(